# How does the `include?` method work?

Tags: ruby

Could someone explain what the logic is behind the `include?` method in the following context?

```
some_var = gets.chomp.to_i

until (1..12).include? some_var
  print "Please, re-type it again!"
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, go to the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F

Answer (score 0):

Returns true if obj is an element of the range, false otherwise. If begin and end are numeric, comparison is done according to the magnitude of the values.

In ur question,

if some_var is within 1 -12 range, it will return true, otherwise , it will return false